# Duda con la frase "ir a [lugar]"

Tags: gramática

Hoy, platicando con amigos, me topé con una duda existencial acerca de la frase:

> Ir a [lugar]

Por ejemplo:

- Voy a **ir a esa casa**.
- Ella va a **ir a Europa**.

Pero por ejemplo, imaginen este contexto: alguien apuntando hacia un lugar a pocos metros de él, y dice: "Quiero ir ahí".

Mi duda es:

¿Cuál es la forma correcta de decirlo: *quiero ir **ahí*** o *quiero ir **a ahí***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si buscamos la [definición](http://dle.rae.es/ahi) en el diccionario de la RAE, nos damos cuenta que el primer significado es:

> En ese lugar o a ese lugar.

por lo que decir:

> Quiero ir a ahí.

sería redundante por lo que la forma correcta es:

> Quiero ir ahí.

Comment: Tienes razon, no me habia puesto a pensar en la palabra "ahi". Yo estaba buscando mas por el lado del verbo "ir". Gracias!