# ¿Por qué se puede omitir un artículo, diciendo "llegar a casa" vs. "llegar a la casa"?

Tags: gramática, diferencias-regionales, artículos

- He aquí un ejemplo *con* el artículo: "Me preocupa que voy a llegar **a la casa** y que una de mis hermanas va a estar aplastada debajo de la casa."
- Y aquí uno *sin* el mismo: "[...] vuelve a hacer la misma pregunta, la vuelvo a contestar, pasa otro rato y el ciclo continúa hasta que me tengo que **ir a casa**." Y uno de la actualidad: "¿Todo el día **en casa**? Descubre nuestr@s profes por webcam"

Yo aprendí a decir los dos, viviendo en Chile.

No es igual que el "zero article" del inglés ("Computers are useful"--"**Los** ordenadores son útiles") porque no se puede utilizar como sujeto de la oración.

[Aquí](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/duda-con-la-frase-ir-a-lugar) se habla de "ir a Europa", y en [otro hilo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20668/do-you-have-to-say-mi-casa-or-can-you-just-say-casa) se sugiere (en comentarios) que es un tema regional:

> I agree and BTW there are regional differences. In Colombia you will
>   almost never hear someone saying "voy a casa" without "mi" while in
>   Spain I think the opposite is true... – DGaleano Apr 27 '17

Pero no se explica el origen de esta construcción, ni se dan las razones.

Encontré también (via una búsqueda Google) un hilo en [wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/ir-a-casa-de-ir-a-la-casa-de.2711971/), basado aparentemente sólo en opinión. ¿Cuál es la razón o el comienzo de esta omisión de un artículo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casa, en el sentido de hogar, parece tener un significado especial en casi todos los idiomas, como si fuera no sólo un sustantivo sino también un adverbio de lugar. Así pues, no haría falta usar el artículo, sino que "ir a casa" sería la misma construcción que "ir a España".
En inglés, se dice "to go home", en lugar de "to go to the home".
En alemán es "nach Hause gehen", en lugar de "nach dem Haus gehen" (Haus con declinación especial).
Lo mismo en neerlandés: "ik ga naar huis" en lugar de "ik ga naar het huis" (también con un adverbio especial "thuis" = en casa, "ik blijf thuis" = me quedo en casa, en lugar de "ik blijf in het huis").
Más ejemplos en idiomas no europeos, en hebreo "ani holej habaitah" = yo voy a casa, en lugar de ani holej labait = yo voy a la casa. Y así en muchos más idiomas.